# Google Cloud Storage List Blob objects with specific file name

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, client-library

With the help of google.cloud.storage and list_blobs I can get the list of files from the specific bucket. But I want to filter(name*.ext) the exact files from the bucket. I was not able to find the exact solution.

For example: buket=data, prefix_folder_name=sales, with in prefix folder I have list of invoices with metadata. I want to get the specific invoices and its metadata(name*.csv & name.*.meta). Also, if I loop the entire all_blobs of the particular folder to get the selected files then it will be huge volume of data and it may affecting performance.

It would be good if someone one help me with this solution.

```
bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket(buket)
all_blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix_folder_name)
for blob in all_blobs: 
  print(blob.name)
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [google-cloud-storage documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) Blobs are objects that have `name` attribute, so you can filter them by this attribute.

```
from google.cloud import storage

# storage_client = gcs client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
# Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

# filter_dir = "filter-string"
[blob.name for blob in blobs if filter_dir in blob.name ]
```

Comment: It's clearly stated in the question that just getting all the objects and looping to match a filter would not be performant.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't allow you to filter, but you can use use the fields parameter to just return the name of the objects, limiting the amount of data returned and making it easy to filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the match_glob Parameter, e.g.

```
bucket.list_blobs(match_glob='*.ext')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter for a prefix, but to filter more specifically (e.g., for objects ending with a given name extension) you have to implement client-side filtering logic. That's what `gsutil` does when you do a command like:

```
gsutil ls gs://your-bucket/abc*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @michael-vehrs answer, if you need to look at all directory levels, be sure to prepend `**/`.

```py
from google.cloud import storage
bucket = storage.Client().bucket("bucket-name")
bucket.list_blobs(match_glob="**/*.ext")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following considering the filters as `name` and `.ext` for the files:

```
all_blobs = bucket.list_blobs()    
fileList = [file.name for file in all_blobs if '.ext' in file.name and 'name' in file.name]

for file in fileList: 
  print(file)
```

Here `name` will be the fileName filter and `.ext` will be your extension filter.